# How can I test for SQL Server connectivity from DOS?

Tags: sql-server, scripting, dos

I am trying to figure out how to "test for connectivity" to a SQL Server database from DOS.   If the connection fails I need to detect the failure.

```
sqlcmd -Q "select 'a test'" -S .\SQLEXPRESS
```

You'll notice that that command doesn't return a true/false value.  Also, if the instance doesn't exist, it times out.  I want something like this that doesn't have a "timeout" issue that makes the user wait:

```
if ( connectivity exists to local )  (
  setup DSN for local
) else (
  setup DSN for local\SQLEXPRESS
)
```

Strangely, **osql.exe -L**  doesn't work for me even though I do have a listening instance.

Comment: BTW, it's not "DOS", but rather the "Windows command line". :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Timeout**: I do not think you will be able to avoid a timeout, if you really want to "check for connectivity". But see below for an alternative.

**Boolean response**: It is enough if the command returns a valid errorlevel. For example, the following code should work:

```
osql -E -S SERVER\INSTANCE -Q ""
if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
  exit script
) else (
  setup DSN
)
```

**Timeout-free alternative**: If the SQL Server is always located on the local machine and you just want to check whether a specific instance is installed or not, try having a look in the registry (using the `reg` command). `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\InstalledInstances` is what you're looking for.